# iTextSharp read timestamp certificate

Tags: c#, timestamp, itext

would sameone mind helping me with code using iTextSharp?
I have signed pdf file and I need to retrieve information about signature and timestamp.
I have no problem with getting signing certificate's information. But I cannot obtain information from TSA certificate. I only get information about issuer and I need to get information about date not before and after too and other.

Here is my code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
AcroFields af = reader.AcroFields;
List<string> names = af.GetSignatureNames();

for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; ++i)
{
    // it is working fine
    string name = (string)names[i];
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7 pk = af.VerifySignature(name);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Podepsal: {0}", pk.SignName));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Datum: {0}", pk.SignDate));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Platnost od: {0}", pk.SigningCertificate.NotBefore));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Platnost do: {0}", pk.SigningCertificate.NotAfter));

    // here I need to help 
    Org.BouncyCastle.Tsp.TimeStampToken tts = pk.TimeStampToken;
    string s = tts.TimeStampInfo.Tsa.Name.ToString();
    // this line returns null
    DateTime dt  = tts.SignerID.Certificate.NotAfter;

}
```

Here is pdf sample http://www.filedropper.com/sample

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the basic signature which has already been verified by iText during your `af.VerifySignature` call, the signature time stamp has not yet been analyzed. In particular the actual TSA certificate has not yet been looked for.

Thus, you first have to identify the certificate in question. Usually it is included in the certificate collection a time stamp brings along, so in the following I assume it is there (it is in case of your sample file). We look it up by issuer and serial number, and then we verify the time stamp with it to be sure it is the right certificate, not a fake. Thereafter you can inspect the certificate as you like.

```
// Define a selector matching issuer and serial number
X509CertStoreSelector selector = new X509CertStoreSelector();
selector.Issuer = tts.SignerID.Issuer;
selector.SerialNumber = tts.SignerID.SerialNumber;

// Retrieve the matching certificates from the time stamp certificate collection
System.Collections.ICollection certs = tts.GetCertificates("COLLECTION").GetMatches(selector);

// Assuming at most one match, retrieve this matching certificate
IEnumerator enumCerts = certs.GetEnumerator();
if (enumCerts.MoveNext())
{
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)enumCerts.Current;

    // Verify that this is the correct certificate by verifying the time stamp token
    tts.Validate(cert);

    // Extracting information from the now verified tsa certificate
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Not before: {0}", cert.NotBefore));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Not after: {0}", cert.NotAfter));
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation, too. Certificates and timestamps are new area for me. And I hope iTextSharp is good choice.

Comment: *"Certificates and timestamps are new area for me."* - In that case I would recommend reading the iText white paper [Digital Signatures for PDF Documents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books#digsig). It is Java centric but ports of the examples are available [on the iText git server](https://git.itextsupport.com/projects/I5NS/repos/tutorial/browse/signatures). *"And I hope iTextSharp is good choice."* - If you just started, you might want to consider using iText 7 for .Net instead of iTextSharp (which is iText 5.5.x for .Net).

Comment: Thank for links. iText7 is therefore higher than iText5? I have already written codes using iText5 - signing pdf, adding timestamp, read signatures and it works fine. Is it worth rewriting it?

Comment: iText 5 is in bug fix mode, no more new features. iText 7, on the other hand, will get more features. If your iText 5 code works fine, I would not yet rewrite it (yet), but I  would seriously look into iText 7 and use it for new projects.

Comment: how to read the TimeStampToken in iText 8? I only can get the TimeStampTokenInfo...

Comment: @robob *"how to read the TimeStampToken in iText 8? I only can get the TimeStampTokenInfo..."* - Please make that a question in its own right.

Comment: here is the question @mkl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76394568/read-timestamptoken-in-itext-8-from-timestamptokeninfo

Comment: @robob As already written in comment to your question, there indeed doesn't seem to be a dedicated getter for the full timestamptoken. I'm afraid, therefore, that you will have to implement parsing the signature container and extracting the tst  yourself.